# How to create several builds of PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm building PostgreSQL(version 9.3.1) from source code in Ubuntu. I'd like to create several builds of Postgres, like pg1, pg2, etc. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way, I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't see why you'd need different builds. Just run `initdb` on multiple data directory and start the same binary using different data directories (and ports of course)

Comment: See http://www.postgresql.org/developer/, https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-procedure.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which os and version are you using?

Even though I disagree with you on doing this, my approach would be to build them and keep the destination directory different from one build to the other. Something like `/usr/local/postgresl-9.3, /usr/local/postgresql-8.4` etc. This would avoid overwriting executable files such as psql or initdb for example. In order to better control the installation then use a package manager to build the packages for your system and install them. (For example in slackware we use the `createpkg` command to bundle up a package so that it can then be handled by the package manager `slackpkg`.

Then for every version you would have to issue an `initdb` on a different base directory and manually start postgres taking care of using the relative `pg_ctl' command.

Be sure to use the full path to the various executable files of the different database versions.

Another issue you will have to take care of is to modify `postgresql.conf` of every instance that you are running in order to make them listen on different ports, should you required to run every database instance simultaneously. Otherwise you can run them one at a time on the default port `5432`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Fabrizio. I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago) and I want to build the same version(9.3.1) of PostgreSQL. The reason to do so is that I need to modify the source code and I want different builds behave differently. So I'm thinking maybe just one executable file would change according to the change in the source code, others like createdb, dropuser should stay the same. Is there any way to keep most of the installation the same, just change the main executable file name which reflects the change in the source code?

Comment: Ok. I don't know the effect but if you tell me this, I would build and install a base version of postgresql. Then modify the source, recompile only the new psql, and copy it to the `bin` directory with a different name, say `psql-V1`. So if you want to call that specific modified version of psql you'd use `/path/to/bin/psql-V1` whereas if you want to use the normal one installed with standard installation the a simple `/path/to/bin/psql` would do.

Comment: I already figured it out last night. I used a similar way as you said. But I didn't touch the `psql`, instead I rename `postgres` as `pg1`, `pg2`,etc. And it works. I think the executable file `postgres` is the one which reflects changes in source code because you start the server by `/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data`, `psql` is just the PostgreSQL command line SQL interpreter. By replacing `postgres` with `pg1`, `pg2`, etc in the command to start the server, I can see the difference in different builds. Anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: BTW, as you are an expert in PostgreSQL, can you ask you something else? It's about the `PREPARE` statement in Postgres. I know by `PREPARE`, the server will save the execution plan and if the similar query being executed again, the server will use the plan it saves instead of optimizing again. Any chance you know where the execution plan is saved? It must be saved in a file in disk, right? I want to know the file name and location. It would be great if you know that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No unfortunately I cannot help you on this one. Why don't you post a question. It seems a very pertinent one to ask as it is a very interesting topic. I'm sure someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the --prefix=PREFIX option while building from source, won't that help? You would also need to look at other options such as --with-pgport=NUMBER to ensure that you don't end up forgetting to change the port in postgresql.conf. Please have a look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-procedure.html for other options you might want to change.

Comment: Exactly; that's all you need to do. Different `--prefix` for each install, initdb each to a separate directory, and set `PGPORT`, edit `postgresql.conf` to set a unique port, or compile in a different default port.